# Is it possible to keep socket.io connections alive after restarting Nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I wrote an online multiplayer turn based game which uses socket.io as transport mechanism.
But the problem is that when I want to change some code in application it must be restarted and this causes socket connections disconnect and reconnect so the game flow including timers, state & ...
will be corrupt.
How can I handle this situation?

I tried to write a reset handler module:

```js
    http.listen(port, () => {
        const argv = process.argv.slice(2)
        if (argv[0] === 'platform-Master') {
            const resetHandler = require('./reset-handler')()
            setTimeout(async () => {
                await resetHandler.findOpenGames()
            }, 3000)
        }
    })
```

But it only works on single process not a cluster or at scale.

Comment: If this is just for development purposes, I wouldn't bother. However, if you're looking to allow the game to recover from network interruptions, the socket message API you've developed for the game needs to handle clients attempting to reconnect.